# Custom Date picker in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, date-picker

I'm trying to use Jquery Date Picker "https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/" in Salesforce Lightning Component. 
I've included required library files. 
It is working in Visualforce Page. But the same is not working in Lightning Component see below error image.

Can anyone please advice me on this?

Lightning Component and Controller

```
<aura:component >
<ltng:require scripts=" /resource/jqueryDatePicker1/jqueryDatePicker1/jquery-1.12.4.js,
                       /resource/jqueryDatePicker1/jqueryDatePicker1/jquery-ui.js"
              />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
```

({

```
  doInit : function(component, event,helper) {
    console.log('doneRendering');
    console.log(jQuery);
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

}
```

})
[image]

VF Page

```
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>

<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$( function() {
    j$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
} );
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you have jQuery included in your '<ltng:require>' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component's init handler is called long before scripts are loaded. So, You need to add `afterScriptsLoaded={!c.methodName}` to the `<ltng:require />` tag, which inturn invokes the controller method where you can access the *jQuery*.

Here's an example:

**component:**

```
    <aura:component>
        <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jqueryDatePicker1/jqueryDatePicker1/jquery-1.12.4.js,/resource/jqueryDatePicker1/jqueryDatePicker1/jquery-ui.js"
                      afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setScriptLoaded}"/>

    </aura:component>
```

**controller:**

```
({
    "setScriptLoaded" : function(cmp){
        console.log(jQuery);
    }
})
```

Right place to do DOM Manipulation is in the Renderer. You can use the `afterRender` to access the DOM.

**Renderer:**

```
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    console.debug('afterRender $: ',jQuery);
}
```

If using `afterRender` doesn't work, look at this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/152973/20830) this might help.

Answer (score 3):

The lightning developer guide strongly recommend against using other javacsript libraries with lightning.  Instead why use lightning components such as

```
<ui:inputDate>
```

or

```
<lightning:input type="date">
```

It's going to save you a bunch of time, and you won't get weird bugs because different javascript libraries are fighting for control of the DOM.

Comment: +1, although I'd add lighting:input is preferable, because then you get an actual Lightning-styled date picker.

Comment: agreed, the lightning namespace is really the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about **ui:inputDate** ? Lightning design system is already included in it.

See the reference here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm

Comment: Have you verified this? I don' think it's formatted using slds and it also says this: Note: This feature isn't generally available unless or until Salesforce announces its general availability in documentation or in press releases or public statements. We can’t guarantee general availability within any particular time frame or at all. Make your purchase decisions only on the basis of generally available products and features.

Comment: Hi! I've made a mistake and linked the v39.0 documentation (Spring 17). It is available in 38 as well, we are using it in our package. It is formatted with slds, the only issue that its not perfect in visualforce, so you might need some extra css hacks. In Lightning Experience it's perfect. Just add the **displayDatePicker="true"** attribute.

Comment: If the picker looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/xmFui then it's not lightning - if it really looks like a lightning picker, I'd be interested to see how you did that.