# Call Js function in the right order

Tags: javascript, lightning, lightning-experience, javascript-controller

I'm trying to call functions in the right order in my lightning component.
First, I would like to call doInit, then, I would like to trigger a function after the script is loaded. How can I achieve this?

component.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <ltng:require
        scripts="{!$Resource.myCustomJsLibrary}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" 
    />

</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getValueFromDatabase");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.settings", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },  
    scriptsLoaded : function (cmp) {
        cmp.get("v.settings");      
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is the function definition you want to call after the scrpitLoaded?

Comment: You just need to call the method inside the `c.scriptsLoaded` which will execute once the scripts have been loaded. Here is the order or execution: [Order of execution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/152973/29734)

Comment: I update my post. I trying first run doinit when its finished run scriptLoaded

Comment: Okay, you want to do something with the value of `settings` attribute? but here it's not sure that the value of `settings` is available because we are making an `asynchronous` request to fetch data from the server which may take some time and you will get the default value.

Comment: The settings value is JSON with settings for my js library. Therefore, it needs to be geted before loading the script.

Comment: Here you can make a small change in the init function location which is using the the JSON data fetched from the server in the init handler;

Comment: Could you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of the `init` handler to fetch the data from the server because it's an Asynchronous Ajax request which may load before the `scriptsLoaded` method call or maybe not sometimes;

So remove the `init` handler and put the JS library initialization method inside the `scriptsLoaded` method, in this first get the JSON data from the server in the same way we are doing in the init handler:

**Component**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <ltng:require
        scripts="{!$Resource.myCustomJsLibrary}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" 
    />

</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp){
        /* initalize attributes here */
    },  
    scriptsLoaded:function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getValueFromDatabase");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.settings", response.getReturnValue());
                /* Here we have the JSON data to initalize the JS library */
                /* Add the code here to initalize the JS library using the JSON data loaded from the server */ 
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: This is it - great working.