# Lighning Component: Rendering Lifecycle and JS static resources

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, static-resources, rendering

I would understand the exact order of execution about "Lightning Component Rendering Lifecycle" and JS static resource.

For example, we have this First Scenario.

Alpha.cmp:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jsResource}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />       

</aura:component>
```

Alpha.js

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
       console.log('doInit');
},

    jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
       console.log('jsLoaded');
}})
```

Who is the order of printing on the console?

In the Second Scenario, I would use a JS static resource (Lealeft.js for example) but I would use some attribute passed by a parent component.

Beta.cmp

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="Tom" type="String"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jsResource}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />       

</aura:component>
```

Beta.js

```
({
    jsLoaded: function (component, event, helper) {
       console.log('Tom=' + component.get("v.Tom"));
    }
}})
```

Is always true that afterScriptLoaded is executed when Rendering LifeCycle is finished?

This topic is very obscure for me!
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**1. Who is the order of printing on the console?**

The afterScriptsLoaded action in the client-side controller is called after the scripts are loaded. Don't use the init event to access scripts loaded by . These scripts load asynchronously and are most likely not available when the init event handler is called.

**2. Is always true that afterScriptLoaded is executed when Rendering LifeCycle is finished?**

1. Component loads and it's init handler will fire(if you have one).
2. Frameworks finishes the rendering the DOM in the browser.
3. ltng:require's afterScriptsLoaded method will be called

Comment: This aligns with what I was going to say, but I was wondering if there is documentation that backs up this answer?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have document around #1 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm but for #2 I took partial ref trevorbliss's (Salesforce guy) comment on  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152968/lightning-components-how-to-make-sure-that-a-script-loaded-via-ltngrequire-is where he said "afterScriptsLoaded will wait for the components afterRender function to be called."